# Размер картинки в lightBox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Вопрос по плагину lightBox jQuery. Если открывается БЕЗМЕРНО ОГРОМНАЯ (over 9000x9000) картинка, то она раздувается на весь экран, заслоняя собой все over the world.  Честно, копался в коде, искал, как можно установить конкретный атрибут width для всех открывающихся картинок - не нашел. (Зато при этом чуть не создал новый плагин!). Подскажите, кто может. Где - в css или в js - можно установить фиксированную ширину картинки.

Comment: К max-width можно еще добавить **!important**

    #lightbox img {
        max-width: 300px; /* своё значение */
        height: auto;
    }

Comment: @Deonis, да нет в плагине элемента с id='lightbox'. Есть #lightbox-container-image-box , но если там установить для img фиксированные значения, картинка станет  маленькой, но сам контейнер lightbox опять же  примет размеры неуменьшенной картинки.

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо за !important! Просто нужно было в одном селекторе указать width: 300px (для img), а в другом width: auto !important (для контейнера).